# copy my cloudService contents from Subscription1 to Subscription2

Tags: windows, azure

I have two windows azure subscriptions

I need to copy my cloudService contents from Subscription1 to Subscription2

Can someone help me with step by step instructions

Comment: What exactly are you trying to copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are unfortunately only two options available and none directly through the portal I'm afraid:

1. Redeploy to the new subscription;
2. Request a ticket to Azure support to move the cloud services to you ( This is viable as the support is great and efficient )

Once logged into the portal, click on your username top right hand corner - "Contact Microsoft Support"

Create the ticket and choose the following:

[image: azure support]